# Replace string with proper tab character in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace, special-characters

I have a string like this:

```
"001234","123","","Automated Letters""\t""Arrears Advice","\\PATH\FILE.doc"
```

Instead of `Automated Letters""\t""Arrears Advice` I need `Automated Letters    Arrears Advice`

How can I make such a find/replace in Notepad++?

I would do this manually, but I have 750 records!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### How do I replace a string with proper tab character?

- First make sure you have "Replace by space" unchecked in "Tab Settings".

  "Settings" > "Preferences" > "Tab Settings" > uncheck "Replace by space"

  - In newer version of Notepad++ this setting is now in "Settings" > "Preferences" > "Language" > "Tab Settings"

  [image]
- Second, you may also want to enable "Show White Space and TAB".

  "View" > "Show Symbol" > "Show White Space and TAB"

  [image]
- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `""\\t""`
- Set "Replace with" to `\t`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

**Before**:

```
""001234","123","","Automated Letters""\t""Arrears Advice","\\PATH\FILE.doc""
```

**After**:

```
"001234","123","","Automated Letters    Arrears Advice","\\PATH\FILE.doc"
```

Note:

- If you have "Show White Space and TAB" the tab characters will display as `→`

  [image]

---

#### Further reading

- [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: @OurManInBananas Apologies for rejecting your edit. I didn't realise you were the OP and had edited your question. I will make the edit myself.

Comment: LOL - there goes my `first accepted edit ` badge, thanks David!

Comment: I don't see this item in the version 7.5.5

Comment: @IhorB. "Settings > Preferences > Language > Tab Settings." in newer versions

Comment: Perhaps put the information about newer versions of Notepad++ first?

Comment: [It changed to *"Language"* in version 7.1 (2016-10-16)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455037/convert-tabs-to-spaces-in-notepad/7471232#7471232) (and was *"Language Menu/Tab Settings"* for some time, changed from *"Tab Settings"*)).